# Deploying contract is always pending . Using web3 to deploy contract

Tags: web3js

**Here is my code for deploying contract**

I get transaction hash, but transaction showing pending alway.

I am doing this on Rinkeby network.

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiDefinition);

var contract =  myContract.deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      //  uint64 maxBalance, uint64 maxSupply, string coinName,uint8 decimalPlace,string simbol, uint unitToSell
      arguments: [deployeParam.max_bal, deployeParam.max_sup, deployeParam.coin_name, 8, deployeParam.symbol, deployeParam.unit_to_sup]
    });


contract.estimateGas().then(function(gas){
  var params = {
    from: web3.eth.coinbase,
    gas: 5000000
  }

  contract.send(params, function (error, transactionHash) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      $j("#page_loader").hide();
      toastr.error(error);
    }
    console.log(transactionHash);
  })
  .on('error', function (error) {
    $j("#page_loader").hide();
    toastr.error(error);
    console.log(error);
  })
  .on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) {
    //setData('contracttransactionhash', transactionHash, false);
    $j("#txhash").text(transactionHash);
    setEtherscanIoLink('contracttransactionhash_link', 'tx', transactionHash);
    result.transactionHash = transactionHash;
   // deployecallback(result);
    $j("#page_loader").hide();
  })
  .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
    document.getElementById('contractaddress').value = receipt.contractAddress;
    setEtherscanIoLink('contractaddress_link', 'address', receipt.contractAddress);
  })
  .on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
    console.log(confirmationNumber);
    console.log(receipt);
  });
});
```

**** Smart Contract *****

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Token {

    /// @return total amount of tokens
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract StandardToken is Token {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
        //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
        //Replace the if with this one instead.
        //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
           emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
        //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
          emit  Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
      emit  Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
}

contract HashnodeTestCoin is StandardToken { // CHANGE THIS. Update the contract name.

    /* Public variables of the token */

    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name;                   // Token Name
    uint8 public decimals;                // How many decimals to show. To be standard complicant keep it 18
    string public symbol;                 // An identifier: eg SBX, XPR etc..
    string public version = 'H1.0'; 
    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;     // How many units of your coin can be bought by 1 ETH?
    uint256 public walletBalance;         // WEI is the smallest unit of ETH (the equivalent of cent in USD or satoshi in BTC). We'll store the total ETH raised via our ICO here.  
    address public fundsWallet;           // Where should the raised ETH go?

    // This is a constructor function 
    // which means the following function name has to match the contract name declared above
     constructor(uint64 maxBalance, uint64 maxSupply, string coinName,uint8 decimalPlace,string simbol, uint unitToSell  ) {
        balances[msg.sender] = maxBalance * 100000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens. This is set to 1000 for example. If you want your initial tokens to be X and your decimal is 5, set this value to X * 100000. (CHANGE THIS)
        walletBalance = balances[msg.sender];
        totalSupply = maxSupply * 100000;                        // Update total supply (1000 for example) (CHANGE THIS)
        name = coinName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        decimals = decimalPlace;                                               // Amount of decimals for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        symbol = simbol;                                             // Set the symbol for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        unitsOneEthCanBuy = unitToSell * 1000;                                      // Set the price of your token for the ICO (CHANGE THIS)
        fundsWallet = msg.sender;                                    // The owner of the contract gets ETH
    }

    function transferToken(address receiver) public returns (bool success)
    {
        balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver] + unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        walletBalance = balances[fundsWallet];
        emit Transfer(fundsWallet, receiver,unitsOneEthCanBuy); // Broadcast a message to the blockchai
        return true;
    }
    function() payable{
        require(transferToken(msg.sender));
        fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
       emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
        //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
        //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
        require(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you provide smart contract code then it will be helpful to understand the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply uploaded contract code, but I feel that problem is with contract deployment using web3 api, it gives me transaction hash but on Rinkey.etherscane it always shows transaction as pending.

Comment: Transaction Id on Rinkeby 
  
 https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x8f5c8ec75fff50e153927906ea75d17f60b00ecee1e3843bffba6f5e846c5fae

Comment: @Siddharth, the deployment process expects that you have a compiled contract ready to go, where is your `compile.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction in pending state has nonce set to 12 and if you look at the *from* account it has no outgoing transaction.

Nonces used in transactions have to be consecutive numbers starting from 0.

For your account the nonce to be mined next should be zero because there's no previous outgoing transaction. Programatically you have to call `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` to obtain the nonce to use.

Your code does not set the nonce so it should be set by the node you are using. Perhaps do you have other transactions pending?

Comment: Yes, I have another transaction pending https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x10e5e81b190ba12257b546acde58459ea536f3e55e5d6e0361cf21f93b29d22c   But I am not understanding this, earlier everything was working fine without setting nonce in the transaction, and suddenly everything stopped can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Possible causes of delay are gas price too low, or gas too high. If gas price is too low your tx will have lower preference to be included in the next block, gas too high makes your tx harder to include in a block.